# Changing observation`s name using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Suppose I have this dataset:

```
Variable <- c("GDP")
Country <- c("Brazil", "Chile") 
df <- data.frame(Variable, Country)
```

I want to change the GDP to "Country_observation" GDP, i.e, Brazil GDP and Chile GDP.

I have a much larger dataset and I've been trying to do this by using

```
df %>% mutate(Variable = replace(Variable, Variable == "GDP", paste(Country, "GDP")))
```

However, it will print the first observation of variable "Country" for every observation in "Variable" that meets the conditional. Is there any way to make paste() use the value of Country on the row it is applying to?

I've tried to use rowwise() and it did not work. I've tried the following code as well and encountered the same problem

```
df %>% mutate(Country = ifelse(Country == "Chile", replace(Variable, Variable == "GDP", 
paste(Country, "GDP")), Variable))
```

Thanks to everyone!

**EDIT**

I can't simply use unite because I still need the variable Country. So a workaround that I found was (I had several other observations that I needed to change their names)

```
df %>% mutate(Variable2 = ifelse(Variable == "GDP", paste0(Country, " ",
Variable), Variable)) %>% 
mutate(Variable2 = replace(Variable2, Variable2 ==
"CR", "Country Risk")) %>% 
mutate(Variable2 = replace(Variable2, Variable2 
== "EXR", "Exchange Rate")) %>% 
mutate(Variable2 = replace(Variable2,mVariable2 == "INTR", "Interest Rate")) 
%>% select(-Variable) %>% 
select(Horizon, Variable = Variable2, Response, Low, Up, Shock, Country,
Status)
```

**EDIT 2**
My desired output was

```
Horizon   Variable   Response Shock Country
1         Brazil GDP   0.0037  PCOM  Brazil
2         Brazil GDP   0.0060  PCOM  Brazil
3         Brazil GDP   0.0053  PCOM  Brazil
4         Brazil GDP   0.0033  PCOM  Brazil
5         Brazil GDP   0.0021  PCOM  Brazil
6         Brazil GDP   0.0020  PCOM  Brazil
```

Comment: `paste` looks OK to me, but without using `replace`. You can also use `unite` from `tidyr` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example should help:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

Variable <- c("GDP")
Country <- c("Brazil", "Chile") 
value = c(5,10)
df <- data.frame(Variable, Country, value)

# original data
df

#   Variable Country value
# 1      GDP  Brazil     5
# 2      GDP   Chile    10

# update
df %>% unite(NewGDP, Variable, Country)

#       NewGDP value
# 1 GDP_Brazil     5
# 2  GDP_Chile    10
```

If you want to use `paste` you can do:

```
df %>% mutate(NewGDP = paste0(Country,"_",Variable))

#   Variable Country value     NewGDP
# 1      GDP  Brazil     5 Brazil_GDP
# 2      GDP   Chile    10  Chile_GDP
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Your suggestion give me an idea on how to tackle it, although I think there might be better ways to solve my problem. The thing with unite is that I still need the variable Country, so I can't get rid of it. So I create a "Variable2" using mutate and after I did some manipulations to reorder it.

Comment: I didn't really get what's your desired output. I'm probably missing something here :-). Can you post how you want it to look like?

Comment: I did an edit so you can see what I was thinking. But again, thank you very much, your answer gave me an idea on how to solve this.

Comment: Unite has an option "remove" that you can set it to False and keep initial columns. Try it.